# Spring Redirect on Post Method Even Though no POST Method is Implemented

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new at Spring,

I have created new Spring MVC project with the following controller:

@Controller
public class AccountController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initForm(Model model){



    WebUser webUser = new WebUser();
    model.addAttribute("user", webUser);
    return "RegistrationForm";
}
```

}

and with the following JSP

### Registration

```
<form:form method="POST" action="user" modelAttribute ="user">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="fName" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="fName" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Last Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="lName" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="lName" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Middle Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="mName" />
        </td>
            <td><form:errors path="mName" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="username" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:input path="password" type="password"/>
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password Confirmation:</td>
            <td><form:input path="confPassword"  type="password" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="confPassword" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email Address:</td>
            <td><form:input path="email" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>Address :</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>Country :</td>
            <td><form:input path="country" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="country" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>State :</td>
            <td><form:input path="state" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="state" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City :</td>
            <td><form:input path="city" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="city" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Street :</td>
            <td><form:input path="street" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="street" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Year of Graduation :</td>
            <td><form:input path="yOfGrad" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="yOfGrad" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

So every time I click on submit the application redirects me to /User even though I have never specified it any where in the application.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'action' attribute in your form:form tag defines the url you are directed to when clicking your submit button, because you entered 'action="user"' you will be directed to '/user'. i'm assuming you're going to want direct to something like '/register', so then you should set 'action="register"'.